# STI Shifter Lever body loose

Tags: road-bike, shimano, shifter

I have Shimano STI shifters (model ST 2300) and the shifter lever (the part for braking and shifting) is loose. So if I hold the head (cockpit) and move it, the head also moves a bit. How can I tighten this?

Comment: This is a bit unclear. Is it the lever itself (which is supposed to be wobbly) or the whole shifter unit?

Comment: If the whole unit moves, peel back the rubber cover front to back. At the outside of the unit there's the 5mm hex head of the bolt that tightens the unit to the handlebar. Check the other one as well. Don't overtighten!

Comment: Hello Mr. Glorfinder, the one that loose is the lever itself not the whole shifter unit. If i hold the lever head( a cockpit-like head with shimano label) and shaking it, it shaked. Its supposed not like that.

Comment: If the lever is lose it could be the pivots which would require some rather tricky disassembly and might prove not repairable. Better try to find some cheap replacement on ebay.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few reasons the brake and shift levers could have become loose with respect to the shifter body, but none of them are repairable. Shimano shift units are essentially riveted together and spare parts are not available (to my knowledge).

This is a Old Ultegra ST-5500 unit I had, similar to a ST-2300

[image]

The levers are fixed to the shifter body by the lever pivot pin. This may  have broken, or come loose from the shifter body. The lever pivot return spring may have broken, which would allow the levers to wobble on the pin.

The levers also pivot laterally on a shaft in the shifter mechanism, this may have broken, or the return spring has failed.

The fix is to find a replacement unit. You should be able to find a left or right hand replacement unit in Ebay, Amazon or other online source,

Comment: Concur - brakes are the most important mechanical component on a bike and they just have to work all the time.  Replacement is the only safe solution.